# Is the drupal.org site hacked?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system, drupal-8

I have just opened the drupal.org site and navigated to the place where it normally shows the latest distributions, now shows some links to free movies. What is happening?

Here is a screenshot of the website, I'm asking about the part circled in pink:

[image: Please see image]

Comment: Is fine, I just checked and everything looks normal to me.

Comment: guess they fixed it up !

Comment: omg!, no , i still see the movie links , lol

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this! I would never have noticed otherwise. The security team has been notified via Slack and is looking into it.

What you are seeing is spam and most likely not a hack in the traditional sense. The new modules and distributions are being flooded with fake projects. But, it is a serious problem. Thanks again for posting.

Edit: It looks like the spam has all been removed.

Comment: shoot, wanted to see a hack, thats more interesting :P, love drupal though :)